# Pagination redirecting to home page

Tags: php, pagination

I am not a coder by any means, just dabbling with PHP. On our website we have this function:

```
public static function mypagination($page, $result)
{
    $totalPages = ceil($result / 100);
    
    $links = "";
    $links .= "<a href='/index.php/flightsearch/findflights?p=1'><div class='flightsearch-pagination-link'>First</div></a>";
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++) { $linkpage = $i; $curpage = $page;
     if($i != $curpage) {
        if($i < ($curpage + 10) && $i > ($curpage - 10))
        {
       $links .= "<a href='/index.php/flightsearch/findflights?p=$linkpage'><div class='flightsearch-pagination-link'>$i</div></a>";
        }
    }
                                           else
                                           {
        $links .= "<div class='flightsearch-pagination-link flightsearch-pagination-active'>$curpage</div>";
    }
                                          }
    $links .= "<a href='/index.php/flightsearch/findflights?p=$totalPages'><div class='flightsearch-pagination-link'>Last</div></a>";
    
    return $links;
}
```

}
?>

When I call the function on another template the pagination does not work and redirects me to the homepage. We have no htt.access file active.
Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is this coding running in an environment where the user has to log into an account?

Comment: Your URLs seem to be structured strangely. You've got `/index.php/flightsearch...` - I think you want to exclude the `index.php` on these other ones. So something like `/flightsearch/findflights?p=1`

Comment: Yes, it does run in a login environment. It's a platform for virtual airlines called phpvms.
It has common classes with functions and templates to display the pages.
I am in no way an expert but I managed to understand how it works and most of the times can fix the issues but not this one.

I will try the suggestion in the second comment and let you guys know. I will also try the flight search module in a vanilla installation of phpvms to see if it's a problem with our current site. Thanks

Comment: I tried the module in a clean phpvms installation and the pagination works fine. The problem is somewhere else on the site but not in the code posted above. Any suggestions as to where to look?